# Lua get last pattern occurrence with string.match

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

I have a string and want the last digit occurrence 
(for now my string.match only take the first occurrence)

```
testvar = "350.11$ i paid, 320$, with visa, cash, 200.21, mastercard, shopping, food"

print ("last number: ".. string.match (testvar, "(%d*%.?%d+)"))
```

in that case I want `200.21` as result (and not `350.11` as by now)

Comment: `string.match (testvar:reverse(), "(%d+%.?%d*)"):reverse()`

Comment: `string.match (testvar, ".*%f[%d.](%d*%.?%d+)")`

Comment: @Egor, those are both good solutions, why not post them?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff +1 from me for the `reverse()` trick.  However, it should be noted that it will work only when the pattern happens to be symmetric (a palindrome if you will).  The given pattern, for example, while it will match the number `.100` when going forward it will fail to match correctly with `reverse()`

Comment: @tonypdmtr - The pattern was also reversed to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
local last
for w in  string.gmatch (testvar, "(%d*%.?%d+)") do
    last = w
end
print(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Egor and all u other guys, u are amazing.

i choosed this two as answer

```
string.match (testvar:reverse(), "(%d+%.?%d*)"):reverse()
string.match (testvar, ".*%f[%d.](%d*%.?%d+)")
```

what do u think is even the better one?